# SQL CLR DDL trigger written on C#

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ddl, sqlclr, ddl-trigger

Is it possible to create a database/DDL trigger in C#?  And, if so, then how?

[EDIT]

Basically, I decided to use CLR for the database trigger because I want to utilize C# SMO to script the objects that change and insert the object script into a table that tracks versions of database objects.

Comment: Triggers can use functions & stored procedures, so I don't see why a SQLCLR function/SP couldn't be used in a trigger (assuming SQL Server 2005+).  The real question is *why* do you feel the need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See: [Programming CLR Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179562.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Or See: [CLR Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093.aspx) Continue toward the bottom for DDL example.